# Lodash create an object from a collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lodash, javascript-objects

With the following array;

```
var arr = [
    {"name": "blah"},
    {"version": "v1.0.0"},
    ...
]
```

I would like to create the following object with **lodash**;

```
var obj = {
    "name": "blah",
    "version": "v1.0.0",
    ...
}
```

**P.S.** Duplicates don't matter as there won't be any here.

Comment: Can we see your implementation or what you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I'm just curious as to what method would be used from lodash or how one might do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using plain JavaScript.

**References:**

1. [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) can be used to concatenate `Objects({})`.
2. [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) can be used to minimize the `Array([])` values.

```js
var arr = [{
  "name": "blah"
}, {
  "version": "v1.0.0"
}];

var obj = arr.reduce(function(o, v) {
  return Object.assign(o, v);
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use lodash when you can do it in pure js?

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "name": "blah"
  }, 
  {
    "version": "v1.0.0"
  }
]

var obj = arr.reduce(function(acc, val) {
  var key = Object.keys(val)[0];
  acc[key] = val[key];
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thank you, I just like lodash for its cleanliness.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash implementation.

```
var arr = [{
  "name": "name"
}, {
  "version": "v1.0.0"
},{
  "manager": "manager"
}];

var result = _.reduce(arr, function(object, value) {
  return _.assign(object, value);
}, {});

console.log(result);
```